# Python Class method to ID intersection of Point w Rectangle uwing set() and Intersection() not working

Tags: python

..trying to define a method within my Point Class that checks interaction with objects of my Rectangle class on interior or boundary using type based dispatch. I tried the code below, but yields: AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'intersects'.

Also, seeking a way to clearly set what intersects at boundary vs. interior. Please advise.

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, height=0):
        self.x = float(x)
        self.y = float(y)
        self.height = float(height)

def intersects(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Point):
            s1=set([self.x, self.y])
            s2=set([other.x, other.y])
            if s1.intersection(s2):
                return True
            else:
                return False
        elif isinstance(other, Rectangle):
             s1=set([self.x, self.y])
             s2=set(other.pt_ll, other.pt_ur)
             if s1.intersection(s2):
                return True
             else:
                return False

class Rectangle(object):    
    def __init__(self, pt_ll, pt_ur):
        """Constructor. 
        Takes the lower left and upper right point defining the Rectangle.
        """
        self.ll = pt_ll        
        self.lr = Point(pt_ur.x, pt_ll.y)
        self.ur = pt_ur
        self.ul = Point(pt_ll.x, pt_ur.y)
```

these are my calling statements:

```
pt0 = (.5, .5)
r=Rectangle(Point(0, 0),Point(10, 10))

s1 = set([pt0])
s2 = set([r])
print s1.intersects(s2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it would be  `intersection()`   `s1.intersection(s2)`, you are using a `set` not a Point object:

```
s1 = set([pt0]) # <- creates a python set
```

To use your `intersects` method you need Point objects:

```
p = Point(3,5) # <- creates a Point object that has intersects method
p2 = Point(3,5)
print(p.intersects(p2))
```

So using your example, you need to access the Point objects using the attributes of the `Rectangle` class:

```
r = Rectangle(Point(0, 0),Point(10, 10))
print(r.lr.intersects(r.ul)) # <- the Rectangle attributes  lr and ul are Point objects because you passed in Point's when you initialised the instance r
```

You can simplify the assignments in Rectangle:

```
class Rectangle(object):
    def __init__(self, pt_ll, pt_ur):
        """Constructor.
        Takes the lower left and upper right point defining the Rectangle.
        """
        self.lr = Point(pt_ur.x, pt_ll.y)
        self.ul = Point(pt_ll.x, pt_ur.y)
```

You can also just use set literals:

```
s1 = {self.x, self.y}
s2 = {other.x, other.y}
```

Comment: I see..I am only not clear on: pt0 = (.5, .5)
r = Rectangle(Point(0, 0),Point(10, 10))
print(r.lr.intersects(r.ul))..  shouldn't the pt0 bein the print stmt. but then how to refer to both r attributes

Comment: `pt0 = Point(.5, .5) print(r.lr.intersects(pt0))` you need to use Point objects to access Point methods, it is not clear what you want to do exactly but accessing Point objects is certainly part of it